# Very 1st attempt to make a call to a jBPM API Throws

Tags: exception, servlets, jboss, jbpm

I am trying to integrate jBPM 5.4 into an existing servlet.

The servlet runs fine with `JBoss 7.1` but it fails with a thrown exception when I add a single jBPM related API.  (I used the evaluation sample from the `jbpm-5.4.0.Final-installer-full.zip` installation as a template.)  I added to the servlet's doPost():

```
KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactor.newKnowledgeBuilder()
```

and the following **exception** is thrown as soon as we execute this statement:

> 20:51:06,394 ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myservlet].[myservlet]]
>   (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Servlet.service() for servlet
>   myservlet threw exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/drools/builder/KnowledgeBuilderFactory    at
>   com.mycompany.myservlet.doPost(myservlet.java:413) [classes:]     at
>   com.mycompany.myservlet.doGet(myservlet.java:120) [classes:]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
>
> We also have:
>
> ```
> import org.drools.KnowledgeBase;
> import org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilder;
> import org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory;
> import org.drools.builder.ResourceType;
> import org.drools.io.ResourceFactory;
> import org.drools.logger.KnowledgeRuntimeLogger;
> import org.drools.logger.KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory;
> import org.drools.runtime.StatefulKnowledgeSession;
> import org.jbpm.process.workitem.wsht.HornetQHTWorkItemHandler;
> ```

Can someone please explain what has gone wrong here?

Thank you.
Al

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the following class: org/drools/builder/KnowledgeBuilderFactory is inside your project classpath (the whole jar file that contains it) and it's also inside your WEB-INF/lib directory inside it's correspondent jar file. 
Doing that will make it work, this doesn't seems to be a Drools or jBPM question at all.. is more related with Web Applications in General.

Comment: Hi Salaboy - Thanks for your quick response.  The problem I have is that I don't know what .jar file(s) to place on the classpath and can't locate a resource that would tell me.  Can you tell me where to look to learn what .jars I need?  Thank you.

Comment: OK, I finally figured this out.  For some reason the .jar files in the .\runtime\lib that is created by the jbpm-5.4.0.Final-installer-full.zip when moved to my WEB-INF\lib did not eliminate this error.  However, I was able to download drools-distribution-5.5.0.Final.zip from http://www.jboss.org/drools/downloads and when I placed those .jars into my .\lib the error was eliminated and I was able to execute that 1st "jBPM test statement" from my servlet.  Can you tell me why the jBPM Installer .\lib .jar files did not work?  Thank you.